# how to change the color of the title bar in a wp7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a question, i need to change the color of the title bar in a WP7 app.

here is my problem:
i have the white theme enabled.
then i generate a app and make the background black.
when i start the app now, the title bar is white and that dont looks good, how can i change the color of the title bar in black theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mango / 7.1, you can set the [BackgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.backgroundcolor%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property of [SystemTray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626537%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). If you're targetting 7.0, your only choice is to hide the SystemTray entirely using [SystemTray.IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.isvisible%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: when i make the SystemTray.IsVisible = false; in my main page i always get: To set SystemTray visibility the RootVisual must be a PhoneApplicationFrame and its Content must be a PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: SystemTray.IsVisible is an attached property which you can apply to the page element.

Answer (score 1):

In code behind :

```
    SystemTray.BackgroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Orange;
    SystemTray.ForegroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue;
```