# Change System Tray Color Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to change the system tray color on Windows Phone from black to white? My app has a white background, so I'd like the system tray to be white, too.

Comment: What do you mean by the system tray? Are you referring to the [Application Bar](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_0K5YG9-Vby8/TKqua6uMbDI/AAAAAAAAAAk/98kKJC4EzQ0/s1600/appbar.png)?

Comment: No, the system tray, as in where the battery and time sit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In Mango / 7.1, you can set the BackgroundColor property of SystemTray. If you're targetting 7.0, your only choice is to hide the SystemTray entirely using SystemTray.IsVisible.

From [how to change the color of the title bar in a wp7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489888/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-a-wp7-app)

Comment: Can you please give me a clear example? I'm very new to this type of coding, I only know a beginners amount of jQuery.

Comment: Figured it out. `SystemTray.SetBackgroundColor(this, Colors.White);`, `SystemTray.SetForegroundColor(this, Colors.Black);`

Answer (score 9):

You could do it in your page XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Blue">
    ...
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to declare this once but not for each page (in `App.xaml` for instance)?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could create your own base page class and do it there, but that's more work and problems elsewhere than simply defining it per page. You could though define a color resource in your app's resource dictionary and use it here with the `{StaticResource}` markup extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it from xaml, you can you this.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage   .........................

xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppThemeColor }" 
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
```

where "AppThemeColor" is a predefined color from style resources for my app.

And if you want to change it from C# code. then you can use following code in OnNavigatedTo() event.

```
SystemTray.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 250, 110, 40); //background color
SystemTray.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 245, 245, 245);//foreground if you need
SystemTray.Opacity = 0.9; // opacity of background color
```