# WP7: access StatusBar in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing application that targets WP7 using Windows Phone 8 SDK so it is also compatible with WP8.

The problem I am facing is that the Status Bar on 720P Emulator is very tall.

Here is the xaml I use:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderBackgroundColor}"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"/>
```

And here is the result
[image: Header without transparency]

If I add transparency to make the status bar shorter I get a black rectangle.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderBackgroundColor}"
shell:SystemTray.Opacity="0.99"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"/>
```

[image: Header with transparency]

---

My question is:

Is there a way to change the color of the black space (I guess there is no way to remove it without targeting WP8 only) ? May be using reflection ..

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it programmatically in your cs as following:

```
SystemTray.BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue; 
SystemTray.ForegroundColor = Colors.DarkGray; 
SystemTray.IsVisible = true;
```

For more you could have a look at this:

[Change System Tray Color Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072410/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me- the code changes the color of the system tray, but the black space remains. As I understand the black space is added because the aspect ration of the screen on 720p is different that the 480 × 800 WP7 screen

Comment: @KamenDobrev Did you try removing the transparency?

Comment: Kamen Dobrev did you try to hide the status bar?

Comment: @Kulasangar If I remove the transparency I get the first image from my question - which is taller than the second image.I want to keep the transparency in order to have more space available in my page.

Comment: But there you don't get the black space right? if you can provide some of the xaml part here!

Comment: @Sandun Harshana  Yes, when I hide the status bar I get the second image from the question, but with the system bar replaced with black space - as a result the black space is even wider. So I guess I need to find out where does this black color comes from.

Comment: @Kulasangar Yes, the black color is changed to SystemTray background color, but this space above my page becomes too tall

Comment: @KamenDobrev I don't think the space is incurring because of the transparency. Tried changing those values? Give the opacity value as 0.0 and see.

Comment: @ Kulasangar  Take a look at the question's images. The only difference between the two images is transparency. The first does not have transparency the second has opacity of 0.99. The first is taller.

Answer (score 1):

You can change SystemTray background color

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Red"
```

Or you can Hide SystemTray

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```